# how to render the rdlc main report with multiple datasources from code behind in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, rdlc

I am generating the pdf file out this code using 2 datatables of dataset, but, the data in pdf appearing from ds.Tables[0] only , not of ds.Tables[1]. Kindly suggest solution..my code is as below ..

```
ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();

viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
viewer.Reset();
viewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = @"D:\Projects\NIKHIL\NIKHIL\Report3.rdlc;
viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"D:\Projects\NIKHIL\NIKHIL\Report3.rdlc;
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables[0]));
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", ds.Tables[1]));
viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

byteViewer = viewer.LocalReport.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

byte[] file = byteViewer;
FileStream stream = new FileStream(FileStorageLocation + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
stream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
stream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple datasource, you must specify which one you refer in your RDLC file.

For every expression you have to edit the formula in this way:

`=First(Fields!nameOfYourField.Value, "nameOfYourDataSet")`

So there will be two cell, one with:

`=First(Fields!nameOfYourField.Value, "DataSet1")`

And the other one with:

`` `=First(Fields!nameOfYourField.Value, "DataSet2") ``